# How to infer 2960S switch base ethernet MAC Address

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, mac-address

Cisco switches seem to allocate unique MAC address for each interface they have, this includes ports and vlan interfaces.

These unique MAC are derived from a "Base ethernet MAC Address", which can be found with:

```
MySwitch#show version
...snip...
Base ethernet MAC Address        : 70:10:5C:22:83:80
```

The interfaces MAC, then look like:

```
MySwitch#show interface FastEthernet0/1
Hardware is Fast Ethernet, address is 7010.5c22.8381
...snip...

MySwitch#show interface vlan87
Hardware is EtherSVI, address is 7010.5c22.83c6
...snip...
```

Then, if I inspect a CDP packet received from a switch, the MAC address on the packet is the actual "port" MAC address.

Is there a reliable way to infer the switch "Base ethernet MAC Address" from receiving such a CDP interface MAC Address, so that I can use that "Base ethernet MAC Address" as a globally unique identifier for the switch device equipment on the network?

Comment: Random question that's more than random: Are you only concerned with 2960S switches, or other Cisco products too?  If you're dealing with other Cisco products, please edit the list of products into your question

Comment: Are the switches missing MGMT ADDR or is the MGMT ADDR not unique in your case? Maybe you could abuse 'VTP Domain' as separator, add customerID there. Then CustomerID+MGMT_ADDR gives you unique identifier for device? Even if what you want to do is possible, would it be possible after upgrade? I would be very uncomfortable building system which assumes it'll continue working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a reliable way to infer the switch "Base ethernet MAC Address" from receiving such a CDP interface MAC Address, so that I can use that "Base ethernet MAC Address" as a globally unique identifier for the switch device equipment on the network?

[You can't determine the base ethernet mac from CDP without guessing or assumptions](http://ccie20728.wordpress.com/2010/10/07/mac-addresses-of-switches/) about how Cisco behaves today (as well as future behavior).  On the other hand, if all you want is a unique identifier, use the Chassis serial number; however, that would require polling the CDP source for [entPhysicalSerialNum](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.11)... a small price to eliminate guesswork.

[entPhysicalSerialNum](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.11) has the added bonus of working across many of Cisco's current platforms.

*Sample SNMP walk of `entPhysicalSerialNum`:*

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -OXsq -v 2c -c ciscoro -m ENTITY-MIB \
  172.16.1.200 entPhysicalDescr
entPhysicalDescr[1] 2650 chassis
entPhysicalDescr[2] 2600 Chassis Slot
entPhysicalDescr[3] C2600 Mainboard
entPhysicalDescr[4] 2600 DaughterCard Slot
entPhysicalDescr[5] 2600 DaughterCard Slot
entPhysicalDescr[6] AIM Container Slot 0
entPhysicalDescr[7] 2600 Chassis Slot
entPhysicalDescr[8] One port Fastethernet TX
entPhysicalDescr[9] AmdFE
entPhysicalDescr[10] AmdFE
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -OXsq -v 2c -c ciscoro -m ENTITY-MIB \
  172.16.1.200 entPhysicalSerialNum
entPhysicalSerialNum[1] JAB05290Z8Q
entPhysicalSerialNum[2]
entPhysicalSerialNum[3] yyyyyyyyyyy
entPhysicalSerialNum[4]
entPhysicalSerialNum[5]
entPhysicalSerialNum[6]
entPhysicalSerialNum[7]
entPhysicalSerialNum[8] 25809045
entPhysicalSerialNum[9]
entPhysicalSerialNum[10]
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

Comment: Is the chassis serial number available over SNMP?

Comment: Yes, please look at `entPhysicalSerialNum`... you have to walk it and cross-reference with `entPhysicalDescr`

Answer (score 0):

The size depends on the specific Cisco device, but you'll notice that the first MAC address ends in `80` (and I've personally only ever seen Cisco switches end in `80` or `00`). It should be possible to take the MAC address you're seeing on the SVI and just mask off `0x7f` on the LSB, though you'd need to confirm the size of the blocks, as they may vary with switch port density, and I know they vary for line cards. Try `sh diag`.